# Docker outbound connection is blocked

Tags: docker, docker-network, opensuse

I am new to the docker world. I am currently setting up an custom application which relies on docker. The setup requires docker container to connect my outside network. All is working well but the container is unable to connect to outside network. After initial investiagtion and tcpdump I came to know that docker container can connect to the outside world. The packet is forwaded to the docker0 interface and docker0 has forwarded the packet to the eth0(physical interface), the eth0 then forwards the packet to the outside world and receives reponse. Now this is where the problem is, the eth0 after receiving reposne doesnot forward the packet to the docker0 interface and finally to the end host.

The below is the iptable run which are all set to default.[image]

[image]

Also tcpdump output
[image]

[image]

Inteface present on th host
[image]

[image]
HOST OS is SUSE Ent linux 15.3
Docker version 20.10.17-ce, build a89b84221c85

I will be very much grateful for any reponse.
Thank You

[image]